# SSRS Force blank pages

Tags: reporting-services

I have some SSRS reports that are generated via a subscription. They Get PDF'd and dropped on a share. The way the report was designed there is a potential for one record (or row if you will) to take up more than one page. I would like to know if it is possible to insert a blank page only after a single record/row takes up more than one page. This includes not showing any headers or footers on the blank page.

I've tried adding a text box with a form feed character to the end of the page, which did not work. I also tried creating a text box that is wider than the page (using an expression to control it's visibility) but that just forced the body of the report to be larger than the report's width which caused blank pages to show up everywhere.

Any help would be great.

Comment: I think your going to find the optional header part difficult. Generally, outside of the print on first/last page option, there is not much you can do to optionally show/hide the static header. There are some wonky workarounds, however.

Comment: This is an untested  guess... Assuming you are controlling the additional page break correctly already, can you put add rectangle that fills the header then cut and paste all the header controls into it, then set the visibility of the the rectangle based on your existing 'add page break' criteria. Repeat for footer.